# Mysql query on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql

I have table Product with fields : id (PK), title (UQ), price, status

I wrote query which should update row if table already has such title

```
INSERT INTO product (title, price, `status`) 
            VALUES("Black boots", 222.18, 1) 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = 125.00 AND `status` = 2
```

That's just example for one product. However, after running this query I am getting message that query was successfuly executed, but price becomes = 0.00 (sometimes 1.00) and status does not change. What is my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update multiple values you need to use the comma operator:

```
INSERT INTO product (title, price, `status`) 
VALUES("Black boots", 222.18, 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = 125.00, `status` = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the argument Values. That allows you to INSERT / UPDATE more then one row

```
INSERT INTO product (title, price, `status`)
VALUES
 ("Black boots", 222.18, 1),
 ("Green boots", 111.22, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = VALUES(price), `status` = VALUES(status);
```